# How to retrieve Operations for a certain Asset?

Tags: assets, operations, javascript-sdk

I've been reading the js-stellar-sdk and I didn't find a way to retrieve the operations for a certain Asset.

How should be this done?

Comment: By operations, do you mean [operations](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/operations.html)  or [offers](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/exchange.html#offers) -- the two have very different meanings in the Stellar network.

Comment: At present time there is no API endpoint that allows to retrieve operations for specific asset. The only way is to run your own Horizon instance and query this information directly from DB.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with two ways.

1. You can scrape and traverse through all operations and save records with your asset into your own database (I'm using this way before I build stellar-core horizon instance). You can use this method if your asset is still low operation volume, because horizon is limit rest api with 3600 request per hour.
2. You can build your own stellar-core horizon instance, this is more flexible way because you had all data you need. I suggest using docker image (quickstart) to start.